# React Big CalendarTimezone issue: Any idea how to use this fix #1046 in 0.10.3 version?

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

We are using 0.10.3 version of [react-big-calendar](https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar) and facing the Timezone issue discussed [here](https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/issues/1083).
Unfortunately we made some custom changes to the 0.10.3 version, so we can't apply that fix(provided in that library for the latest versions) to the version we are using. How to apply the fix in the older version 0.10.3 without upgrading it to a new version?

Comment: There is no general way per se to do it. You'd need to take the PR and backport it to your fork adopting to your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

The (0.36.0) latest version of RBC has full timezone support now, when using either the `momentLocalizer` or the new `luxonLocalizer`. Doc site isn't up to date yet, but if you run the 'examples' locally you'll find all the info.